# Apache 2.4/PHP-FPM ProxyPassMatch and access restriction

Tags: security, mod-rewrite, php-fpm, mod-proxy, apache-2.4

I've got Apache/PHP setup exactly like this: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM

It includes the `ProxyPassMatch` rule as mentioned:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/path/to/files/$1
```

This sends all requests with `.php` in it to a proxy, and ultimately serves the PHP just fine.
However, I've been trying to do some access control and the proxying seems to take precedence. My folder structure is like this:

```
/             <-- PHP files
/extra/       <-- PHP files
/css/
/img/
```

There should be access to the PHP files in the root directory, but I want to restrict access to the `extra` dir. I've added these lines to my main config:

```
<Directory "/extra">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

But the PHP files are still executed... When I put a different kind of file in the folder, it is successfully blocked, so the directive works. I'm guessing the `ProxyPassMatch` rule is prohibiting it from working for PHP files.

I've tried a couple of things, like putting the `ProxyPassMatch` rule inside a `<Directory>` block (doesn't work, because you cannot use `ProxyPassMatch` inside such blocks) and substituting `ProxyPassMatch` for a `RewriteRule` with the `[P]` flag (similar to this: [Apache 2.4 + PHP-FPM + ProxyPassMatch](https://serverfault.com/questions/450628/apache-2-4-php-fpm-proxypassmatch), but it didn't get proxied).

My question is almost exactly the same as this one: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/417758. However, it did not get a definitive answer.

What confuses me is you need to have the proxy-rule in place, but when you put it in, nothing else seems to matter (.htaccess also does not work anymore). Furthermore, this raises questions about security. Everything with `.php` in it remains untouched by my fancy access provisions and goes straight through to the system's internals. How can I combine PHP-FPM with proper security rules in Apache?

Answer (score 1):

With `ProxyPassMatch` `.htaccess` files will be ignored completely. Something similar is probably happening with the ignored directives in the main configuration file.

Try using `FilesMatch` and `SetHandler` instead, as described in a [2015 answer to the question you already linked to](https://serverfault.com/a/672969/318307), and [this blog post](https://ma.ttias.be/apache-2-4-proxypass-for-php-taking-precedence-over-filesfilesmatch-in-htaccess/).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in front of your ProxyPassMatch

```
ProxyPass /extra !
```

If ProxyPass finds /extra is the current folder, ProxyPassMatch will not be used. Important is the ! at the end of the line.

See here for more information:
[ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

Comment: A bit more explanation would improve this answer.

Comment: Interesting idea, the apache docs explain excluding files or directories like this. However, it does not seem to do anything (I've put it right in front of `ProxyPassMatch` and checked the syntax twice). Even so, if it would work, I think the files in `/extra` would never be proxied. That is not what I want, I only want to prohibit direct access.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it's on the first page when I search for a solution to access control for Apache when using `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassMatch`. So it may help someone else who started here instead of Apache's docs.

The solution is to include a section below the Proxy declarations:

```
<Proxy "*">
  Require ip 192.168
  Require host example.com
</Proxy>
```

This is all per the [mod_proxy documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).