# Does Apache's ProxyPassMatch trump rewrite rules?

Tags: apache-2.4

I have the following in a virtualhost section:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/local.mysite/wordpress/$1
```

In my testing, I found that adding a rewrite rule of `RewriteRule ^/wordpress/wp-content/(.*)$ /wp-content/$1 [L]` had no effect for a URL like :

```
http://local.mysite/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/simple-post-thumbnails/timthumb.php?src=....
```

Is this because all requests containing `.php` in the name are passed to fcgi and so all rewrite rules are ignored?

Comment: It might simply be a question of order, if the ProxyPassMatch comes before your RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a proxypassmatch or proxypass it passes the php script to be processed by the php-fpm process and the php-fpm process ignores .htaccess rules.
One way to avoid it is to use apache sethandler as is explained in this answer https://serverfault.com/a/672969/189511,

```
 <FilesMatch \.php$>
   SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/socket.sock|fcgi://unique-domain-name-string/"
 </FilesMatch>
```

I'll copy the full solution here

> After hours of searching and reading Apache documentation I've come up
>   with a solution that allows to use the pool, and also allow the
>   Rewrite directive in .htaccess to work even when the url contains .php
>   files.
>
> ```
> <VirtualHost ...>
>
>  ...
>
>  # This is to forward all PHP to php-fpm.
>  <FilesMatch \.php$>
>    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/socket.sock|fcgi://unique-domain-name-string/"
>  </FilesMatch>
>
>  # Set some proxy properties (the string "unique-domain-name-string" should match
>  # the one set in the FilesMatch directive.
>  <Proxy fcgi://unique-domain-name-string>
>    ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=240
>  </Proxy>
>
>  # If the php file doesn't exist, disable the proxy handler.
>  # This will allow .htaccess rewrite rules to work and 
>  # the client will see the default 404 page of Apache
>  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
>  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
>  RewriteRule (.*) - [H=text/html]
>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```
>
> As per Apache documentation, the SetHandler proxy parameter requires
>   Apache HTTP Server 2.4.10.
>
> I hope that this solution will help you too.